# How to create uninstall.exe

Tags: uninstallation, uninstallstring

How to create uninstall.exe for a single self contained app.exe winforms c# project. I am working on a project that is run directly from single app.exe without installation and there should be a uninstall.exe that will delete app.exe file and delete itself. Can some one help me?

Comment: This seems like an unusual requirement. Usually if an app doesn’t require installation, then it also doesn’t require uninstallation, you would just delete the file. What would the uninstaller to do besides delete the app.exe?

Comment: I want when app.exe is run then it should create an uninstall.exe in some location and this uninstall.exe will delete app.exe and itself.